# I am writing an iPhone Notes Client, can I integrate it with Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, iphone

First, I'm not sure if this is the correct venue to be asking this question, so if not, I apologize.

I'm a big fan of Tomboy notes and the ability to sync them with UbuntuOne. I like having my notes accessible across all of my computers, and would like to be able to do the same thing on my phone. I know there is a client for Android, but from what I could tell, no such client exists for iPhone.

I'd been meaning to play around with learning some iPhone development anyway, so I did some reading on iOS development, spent some time, and wrote an application that does most everything that I use Tomboy for. It can link to your Ubuntu One account, sync notes back and forth, and it supports the majority of the formatting (bold, underline, highlight, etc.) options. I'm sure that someone more experienced in iOS development could have done a better job, but it seems to work well enough for what I need.

I'd like to put it in the apple app store for free and make the source available (as I'm sure it could stand to be fixed and refined by someone more knowledgeable than myself), but I'm not sure what the rules are for such a thing. Right now I've just got it on my own computers and haven't gone to the trouble to pay to enter the Apple developer program because I have some questions about whether I can do so, before I spend the money.

As it stands right now, I've used the Ubuntu font in the application (font.ubunu.com), as well as some mentions of Ubuntu itself and the Ubuntu One logo. I suspect the use of the font is probably okay, but I have my doubts about the logo, so some rebranding might be necessary. More than that, am I even allowed to access the Ubuntu One Notes service in this way? I know Ubuntu has some mobile applications for syncing other Ubuntu One services (music, contacts, etc.), but I couldn't find mention of notes, and as I said before, I know that Tomboy and Tomdroid are already utilizing Ubuntu One as a sync destination.

Basically, I was hoping someone might either know the answers to some of these questions, or be able to point me toward someone who does. Obviously I can just continue using this application for myself as it does what I wanted, but I thought it might be nice to make it available for other people and, if someone more knowledgeable about iOS development were so inclined, to improve it.

Sorry this was a bit long, and thanks!
Adam

Comment: How is the project going? I would love to use this!

Comment: I would really love to use your app, did you put it in the app store yet? If not could you put it somewhere else for download?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm only going to answer about Ubuntu One; your question is actually several questions rolled into one, and I can only answer for what I know.

You can't use the Ubuntu One logo as your application icon. You can, however, use the Ubuntu One logo and name within your application if your intention is to use it to indicate a “works with Ubuntu One”, as long as you don't do anything obviously nasty.

We will have a specific “works with Ubuntu One” soon, but meanwhile please use some text such as “works with” and the icon.

If you need any special sizes or colours [please contact us](https://one.ubuntu.com/support/contact/) in private.

Hoping to see your app live soon!

Comment: Okay, great. That makes sense. I wasn't really expecting to be able to use the logos outright, but I was unclear as to how best to make the association clear. I've used the contact form and so I'll move this conversation to whatever that results in.  Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

To add to what Chipaca's written, I should say that you are not only allowed but *encouraged* to build apps like this that work with Ubuntu One. I'm currently in the process of documenting all these APIs as part of the nascent Ubuntu One app developer programme, and so I'm here to help; if there's anything I can do to make it easier for you to build apps like these, please let me know; I'm here for you :-)

Comment: Haha.. I wish now that I'd asked the questions before I built it. I started out by just watching the HTTP traffic to see what the requests looked like and deciphered it from there before I eventually found the Tomboy API which filled in some gaps.  Thanks, and I'll definitely let you know when I have more questions.